# Laptop heatsink screws getting loose by themselves

Tags: laptop, heatsink, screws

I own a HP dv6 6008eg laptop and noticed some days ago that some odd noise is coming from inside during gaming, mostly when the temp reaches about 80°C and the fan seriously kicks in.

Taking it apart today, I saw that one screw on the CPU and another on the GPU were completely loose, while the others were fine. After an almost full reassembly and realising that I forgot something, I disassembled it again only to find out that those two faulty screws were again loose.

Now the laptop is fully assembled and I tested it with some games, the sound is not as strong now as it was before and at first there was no sound at all. I suspect the fan vibrations untighten those heatsink screws, since I don't believe anything else could cause this.

So, could anyone please help me getting those screws to stay tight? How dangerous is this for the laptop? Is there any chance the cause of the sound is not this and something else? The fan is as clean as it can get, though.

Comment: Are the screws damaged?  Are threads worn out?  Screws should not unscrew themselves, not sure how we can help you, this problem is unlikely to exist in very many cases.

Comment: Are the screws going into metal or plastic? If plastic, it's probably worn due to overtightening or contamination. If metal, you can use thread lock to hold them in place against vibration.

Comment: Ever heard of spring washer?

Answer (score 0):

The plastic part on the heatsink is likely worn and will not hold the screws in place. I recommend getting it [replaced](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MZB29MY). Best if you can get a hp oem part, but if price or scarcity is a factor you may just have to go with a generic.

Other idea was to glue down the heatsink, but could create unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a product like [LocTite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FIXQXK).  It is designed to prevent screws from coming loose.

Comment: Only use this if the threads are going into metal. Do not use it with plastic.